# When outof scope, will std::bind prolong object lifetime, like char array, if so, how does it work?

Tags: c++, bind

**I am uisng char arry in scope and bind it to `ThreadPool` to do task, like below:**

```
void test_thread_pool_arr(){

    auto lb_print = [](const char* str){
        info("print msg: %s, and i will sleep 2s", str);
        sleep(2);
    };

    ThreadPool tp(3);

    {
        char arr[10];
        memset(arr, '1', sizeof arr);
        arr[9] = '\0';

        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, arr));
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, arr));
    } // leave scope so, arr should be invalid

    info("leave scope....");

    tp.exit(); // tell ThreadPool to join and then exit.
    tp.join();
    info("ending....");
}
```

**Output as below:**

```
2018/12/06-20:07:59 leave scope....
2018/12/06-20:07:59 print msg: 111111111, and i will sleep 2s
2018/12/06-20:07:59 print msg: 111111111, and i will sleep 2s
2018/12/06-20:08:01 ending....
```

**I think when arr leave it's scope,it should be destoryed, but it's output normal(the task function lb_print just get the address of arr, but arr is being destoryed).**

**Why? Does std::bind prolong it lifetime? If so, how does it works?**

**Another example with class object:**

```
class BindScope{
    public:
        BindScope(int i=0):n_(i){
            info("BindScope ctor %d", n_);
        }

        ~BindScope(){
            info("BindScope ~dtor %d", n_);
        }

        void print()const{
            info("do print %d", n_);
        }

    int n_;
};

void test_thread_pool_scope(){
    auto lb_print = [](const BindScope& bs){
        bs.print();
    };

    ThreadPool tp(3);

    {
        BindScope bs(4);
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, std::ref(bs)));
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, std::ref(bs)));
    }// bs be destoryed, but tp do task normally

    info("out scope");
    tp.exit();
    tp.join();
    info("ending.........");
}
```

Output as below:

```
2018/12/06-20:14:03 BindScope ctor 4
2018/12/06-20:14:03 BindScope ~dtor 4
2018/12/06-20:14:03 out scope
2018/12/06-20:14:03 do print 4
2018/12/06-20:14:03 do print 4
2018/12/06-20:14:03 ending.........
```

We can see that when object `bs` goes out of scope, its be destoryed, but the `ThreadPool` do task normally. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually both cases cause undefined behaviour. You reference to dangling pointer and dangling reference. Anything can happening. And it can work "normally" in some cases.

Comment: Well, it's hard to provide example that demonstrates such situation, cause it's UB, you cannot predict results.

Comment: I have solve an example, and authenticate you opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The char array lifetime is not extended, just a pointer to it.

You follow the dangling pointer and experience undefined behaviour.

If it was  a std array it would be copied.

Undefined behaviour can do anything, includong "appear to work".

Comment: @Jayhello undefined behaviour means *anything* can happen. You've left the realm of predictable results

Comment: I have solve an example, and authenticate you opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it will reference to dangling pointer. Example like below:**

```
class BindScope{
    public:
        BindScope(int i=0):n_(i){
            arr_ = new char[n_+1];
            memset(arr_, '1', n_);
            arr_[n_] = '\0';

            info("BindScope ctor %d", n_);
        }

        ~BindScope(){
            info("BindScope ~dtor %d", n_);
            delete[] arr_;
        }

        void print()const{
            info("do print %d, %s", n_, arr_);
        }

    int n_;
    char* arr_; // test for outof scope
};

void test_thread_pool_scope(){
    auto lb_print = [](const BindScope& bs){
        bs.print();
    };

    ThreadPool tp(3);

    {
        BindScope bs(4);
        bs.print();  // test for normally output.

        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, std::ref(bs)));
        tp.addTask(std::bind(lb_print, std::ref(bs)));
    }  //  bs got destoryed.

    info("out scope");
    tp.exit();
    tp.join();
    info("ending.........");
}
```

**Output as below:**

```
2018/12/06-20:36:43 BindScope ctor 4
2018/12/06-20:36:43 do print 4, 1111    // output normal
2018/12/06-20:36:43 BindScope ~dtor 4
2018/12/06-20:36:43 out scope
2018/12/06-20:36:43 do print 4,         // output wrong
2018/12/06-20:36:43 do print 4,         // output wrong
2018/12/06-20:36:43 ending.........
```

we can see that, when `bs` got destored, the `ThreadPool` task `lb_print` works wrong(outpur wrong).